# Matrix multipication?

Tags: matrices

I have a relation

$A^{-1}BA=B''$ and $AA^{-1}=I$
where $A,B$ are general matrices

My question is can I write above relation  in following form by multiplying both sides of above equation from left side with $A$  as following

$BA=AB''$ or it will take form

$BA=B''A$

Comment: The first form is correct. In general, when there are two expressions on either side of an equal sign, multiply both on the left side, or both on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the comments is perfectly correct, but we can also say a few things more.

In general, matrix multiplication is associative, but not commutative. As pointed out, if you multiply on the left, you must stay on the left, and likewise for the right. There are some times when matrix multiplication $is$ commutative though. For example, if you are multiplying by a matrix which is either the identity or some multiple of it.

Also, when you learn about diagonalization of matrixes, you will see that if both matrixes are simultaneously diagonalizable, they are also commutative. Simultaneously diagonalable means that if you consider the equations $Ax = \lambda_1 x$ and $Bx = \lambda_2 x$, for given matrixes $A, B$, then these have the same solutions in terms of $\lambda_j, j=1,2$ and $x$, which are called eigenpairs.